# Cannot access Jenkins server if a group is added to Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy?

Tags: jenkins, permissions, authorization

Scenario:-
Group name "developers" which consists of john,mark and sam.
I am using Active Directory for authorization.
I have added group "developers" in PBMA.
Now any of these three users should be able to login but I get error as 
"x is missing the Overall/Read permission" BUT I have given all permissions including admin to this group in Project as well as in global configs.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research here what I found.
We were using Active Directory Plugin and our group name was in lower case.
We were adding group to  Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy(PBMAS) but it didn't work.
Later we added the group name in Upper case and it worked.
From our investigation we found that in order to add groups to Authorization it should be in Upper case.

Eg:-
Group name:- developers
when added in PBMAS didn't work.
But when added as  "DEVELOPERS" in PBMAS , voila - it worked.